# Make `minikube service` tunnel on darwin bind to a specific port

Tags: macos, docker, kubernetes, minikube, darwin

On Mac, minikube needs to create a tunnel to expose services to the host machine. Normally, it chooses a random port from the [available port range](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#increasing-the-nodeport-range) for the host side of the tunnel.

My problem is that I am creating a web service which uses Oauth 3rd party authentication. The authorized redirect URIs cannot contain port ranges or wildcards. So, a valid redirect URI can be `http://127.0.0.1:30200/callback`, but it can't be `http://127.0.0.1:*/callback`, or something like that.

Is there a way to tell minikube to tunnel through a specific port every time, or fail if the port is unavailable? I'm struggling to find this option.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up changing the service type from `NodePort` to `LoadBalancer`, and then `minikube tunnel` "just works" and binds the load balancer to the same port on the host machine.